# Variables Won't Extract - Controller To View Codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, extract

I'm passing data from my controller:

```
$data = $this->post->get_post($postID);
$data['errors'];
$this->load->view('register_user.php', $data);
```

But For some reason, when trying to extract the array in the view, like so:

```
extract($data);
foreach ($data as $result)
{
echo $result,'<br>';
}
endforeach;
```

I get `$data is null` error.

What's the reason for the null array?

A couple things:

1. 'post' is a model which i construct into the class,which pulls a certain row in a certain table that contains all of the details for a specific posts. When trying to echo the array in the controller, it shows.
2. could inserting a new key and value into the array ('errors'=> 0 ) the cause for the error?

Comment: please `var_dump($data);` in controller. You will see that your data is a array of objects (depends on your model method either you use `..->result()` or `...->array_result();` so please also show us model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You fetch your data in view like this.

`$errors`

Whatever you put in `$data` variable array and you pass $data variable to view, is "converted" in a such way that every element (index) is a variable in view.

So in controller we have `$data['news'] = array(); $data['errors'] = array();` But in views we have only 2 variables that we can work with `$news` and `$errors`.

please make adjustment to your code as follows

```
$data['post'] = $this->post->get_post($postID);
var_dump($data['post']);
$this->load->view('register_user.php', $data);
```

and in view

`foreach ($post as $result)...`

Comment: This works, But I still can't assign the `errors` in the controller.... only in the view, which means the result will always be the same. I don't want that to be the case - I need for the controller to receive information and decide which `$errors` value to send to the view.

Comment: OK! Got it eventually. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can access your data with array keys directly in view

For example:

```
if 
    $data = array(
        'test1' => 'test1_data',
        'test2' => 'test1_data'
    );
```

In this case you can access `$test1` directly like

```
<?php echo $test1; ?>
```